# Paging GraphQL results in PowerBI

Tags: github, graphql, powerbi

I have a working independent query against github graphQL, but when I'm trying to page on it, I am having trouble getting to the correct depth of the JSON object I think to store the paging data for looping.

Working Query

```
let
vUrl = "https://api.github.com/graphql",
vHeaders =[
        #"Method"="POST",
        #"Content-Type"="application/json",
        #"Authorization"= "Bearer <token>"
    ],
// Notice the quote escaping here
vContent=Text.ToBinary("{""query"": ""query _Welcome_to_Altair_G518 { search(query: \""org:<org>\"", type: REPOSITORY, last: 100) { nodes { ... on Repository { name defaultBranchRef { name target { ... on Commit { history(first: 100, since: \""2024-01-29T00:00:00\"") { totalCount nodes { ... on Commit { committedDate additions deletions url author { name email } } } } } } } } } }}""}"),
Source = Web.Contents(vUrl, [Headers=vHeaders, Content=vContent]),
#"JSON" = Json.Document(Source),
data = JSON[data],
search = data[search],
nodes = search[nodes],
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(nodes, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
#"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"name", "defaultBranchRef"}, {"Column1.name", "Column1.defaultBranchRef"}),
#"Expanded Column1.defaultBranchRef" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "Column1.defaultBranchRef", {"name", "target"}, {"Column1.defaultBranchRef.name", "Column1.defaultBranchRef.target"}),
#"Expanded Column1.defaultBranchRef.target" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1.defaultBranchRef", "Column1.defaultBranchRef.target", {"history"}, {"Column1.defaultBranchRef.target.history"}),
#"Expanded Column1.defaultBranchRef.target.history" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1.defaultBranchRef.target", "Column1.defaultBranchRef.target.history", {"totalCount", "nodes"}, {"totalCount", "nodes"}),
#"Expanded nodes" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Column1.defaultBranchRef.target.history", "nodes"),
#"Expanded nodes1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded nodes", "nodes", {"committedDate", "additions", "deletions", "url", "author"}, {"committedDate", "additions", "deletions", "url", "author"}),
#"Expanded author" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded nodes1", "author", {"name", "email"}, {"name", "email"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded author",{{"Column1.name", "Repo"}})
in
#"Renamed Columns"
```

Query where I'm trying to page and get more than the first 100 commits. Ideally, I'd like to do the repo also, but I can work with a smaller date range to limit the # of repos. I'm currently getting

> "Error: The parameter is expected to be of type Text.Type or
> Binary.Type Details: data=[Record]"

It seems to be having a hard time with the defaultBranchref list originally

```
let
FnGetOnePage = (cursor) =>
let     
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(
    "https://api.github.com/graphql",
    [
        Headers=[
            #"Method"="POST",
            #"Content-Type"="application/json",
            #"Authorization"="Bearer <token>"
        ],
    Content=Text.ToBinary(Text.Replace("{""query"": ""query _Welcome_to_Altair_G518($cursor: String){ search(query: \""org:<org>\"", type: REPOSITORY, first: 100) { nodes { ... on Repository { name defaultBranchRef { name target { ... on Commit { history(first: 100, since: \""2024-01-29T00:00:00\"", after:$cursor) { totalCount nodes { ... on Commit { committedDate additions deletions url author { name email } } } pageInfo { endCursor hasNextPage } } } } } } } }}""}", "($cursor: String)", "($cursor: String" & cursor & ")"))
    ]
    )),
    #"JSON" = Json.Document(Source),
    data = JSON[data],
    search = data[search],
    nodes = search[nodes],
    defaultBranchRef = nodes[defaultBranchRef],
    target = defaultBranchRef[target],
    history = target[history],
    pageInfo = history[pageInfo],
    hasNextPage = pageInfo[hasNextPage],
    endcursor = pageInfo[endCursor],
    res = [Data=nodes, Cursor=endcursor, HasNext=hasNextPage]
in 
    res,
Pages =
    List.Generate(
        ()=>[res = FnGetOnePage("")],
        each [res][Cursor] <> null,
        each [res = try FnGetOnePage("=\""" & [res][Cursor] & "\""") otherwise null],
        each if [res] <> null then [res][Data] else null
    ),
   #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Pages, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)
```

in
#"Converted to Table"